# How can i accomplish the following using knockout js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to learn knockout.js and in an attempt to make my own code, this is what i came up with. It is a hotel package proposal where a user clicks on add hotel, and text boxes relating to hotels appear. I also want the initialized data to show in the text boxes.
I'm using this as reference.

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html

Right now, the text boxes are not showing the initial data, and the code breaks when i click on add hotels

my knockout code

```
function Proposal(details,fee, hotelproposal) {
    var self = this;
    self.details = details;

    self.fee = fee;
    self.hotelproposal= ko.observableArray(hotelproposal);
}

function hotel(hotelname,checkin,checkout,roomtype, viewtype){
    self.hotelname=hotelname;
    self.checkin=checkin;
    self.checkout=checkout;
    self.roomtype=roomtype;
    self.viewtype=viewtype;
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ProposalViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.info=ko.observable( new Proposal("these are the details", 1200,[new hotel("Hilton","202020","202020","double", "city") , new hotel("Hilton2","2020201","2020201","triple", "sea")]));   

    self.addhotel = function(hotel) {
        self.info.Proposal.hotelproposal.push({
            hotelname:"",
            checkin:"",
            checkout:"",
            roomtype:"",
            viewtype:""
        });
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ProposalViewViewModel());
```

my html code:

```
<h2>Proposal</h2>
<div >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Details</th>

            <th>fee</th>
            <th>Hotels</th>

        </tr>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: info">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind='value: Proposal.details' />

                </td>

                <td><input data-bind='value: fee' /></td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: info.hotelproposal">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input data-bind='value: hotelname' /></td>
                                <td><input data-bind='value: checkin' /></td>
                                <td><input data-bind='value: checkout' /></td>
                                <td><input data-bind='value: roomtype' /></td>
                                <td><input data-bind='value: viewtype' /></td>


                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addhotel'>Add hotel</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This code is not working. Can someone point out whats wrong?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What is expected result and what is actual one? Please clarify.

Comment: Quiet a few issues with your scripts ... created a fiddle that works https://jsfiddle.net/gkvhjbnL/1/ .. use the chrome's console (or any other js developer tool) to look at javascript exceptions and that would give an idea on what is missing .. like for example "ko.applyBindings(new ProposalViewViewModel())" is misspelled to begin with ... should have been "ProposalViewModel"

Comment: Thankyou so much for taking out the time to look at my code. This will help me alot! :)